# Set badge count when application is killed/force quit

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I need to set badge count when application killed/force quit, i tried silent notifications (you can see badge_reset logic below) but they only works when application in foreground/background.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if let action = userInfo["action"] as? String {
        switch action {
            case "badge_reset":
                    if let badge = userInfo["badge"] as? String {
                        let badge: Int = (badge as NSString).integerValue;
                        if (badge >= 0) {
                            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge;
                        } else {
                            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
                        }
                    }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else {
        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {

                let title = alert["title"] as! String;
                let body = alert["body"] as! String;
                let link = userInfo["link"] as! String;

                if (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active) {
                    if let controller = self.window?.rootViewController {
                        let image = UIImage(named: "Notification");
                        let announcement = Announcement(title: title, subtitle: body, image: image, duration: 10, action: {
                            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                            if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShitstuffController") as? ViewController {
                                controller.loadViewIfNeeded();
                                controller.link = link;

                                self.window?.rootViewController = controller;
                            }
                        })

                        Whisper.show(shout: announcement, to: controller)
                    }
                }

            } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
                //
            }
        }
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let content = response.notification.request.content;

    if let link = content.userInfo["link"] as? String {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShitstuffController") as? ViewController {

            controller.loadViewIfNeeded();
            controller.link = link;

            self.window?.rootViewController = controller;
        }
    }

    completionHandler();
}
```

I am sure it is possible because Gmail update badge count regardless app is active/hidden/killed/quit/etc, but can't find how, some topics on StackOverflow says WhatsUp/Gmail just spams "read notification" status, but i can't find any information about such type of notification.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this method :

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // set your badge 
}
```

Comment: It's an application method, it can't be called when application is force killed by user.